# Postgres13.4: Unable to Create Tables in Schema

Tags: postgresql

Dear all: I am working with Postgres13.4, and trying to create tables within a schema.  Unfortunately, I just cant seem to find the right combination when defining the database and schema objects.  I need to create a Database and a schema as postgres - I dont want the users to own either the database or the schema - only the objects in the schema.  I have tried several variations of the following and still run into trouble:
(as user postgres)
...

```
CREATE DATABASE new1;

CREATE USER user1 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';

CREATE ROLE role1;

GRANT TEMPORARY ON DATABASE new1 TO role1;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE new1 TO user1;

GRANT role1 TO user1;

\connect new1

CREATE SCHEMA schema1;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema1 TO ROLE1;

-- *** ALTER PRIVILEGES - TABLES

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema1 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO role1;

-- *** ALTER PRIVILEGES - SEQUENCES
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema1 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES TO role1;

-- *** ALTER PRIVILEGES - FUNCTIONS
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema1 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS TO role1;

-- *** ALTER PRIVILEGES - TYPES
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema1 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TYPES TO role1;
```

...
After creating this database, I then logout/login as user1.

- I verify that schema1 exists and is owned by postgres:

  SELECT CATALOG_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, SCHEMA_OWNER FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
- Confirm that user1 does have privileges on the schema:
  SELECT rolname, has_schema_privilege(rolname, 'public', 'usage') from pg_roles where rolname='user1';
- The list of schemas does show that role1 has privileges (\dn+): role1=U/postgres
- However, as user user1, executing display privileges (\dp) indicates that user1 has no privileges: (0 rows)
- If user1 attempts to create a table, the following error is displayed: permission denied for schema schema1

Is there something obvious that I missed here?  How to enable user1 to create a table (and other objects) within the schema?  THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Jeff's answer, the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` will only apply to objects created as the user that ran the statements. To automatically grant privileges on objects created by `user1`, you have to run

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE user1 ...
```

Comment: Guys: THANK YOU VERY MUCH.  I have been working on this for days to get this working.  You provided exactly what I needed to resolve the problem.  THANK YOU.

An interesting side note: some commands are still returning nothing.  Examples: display privileges (\dp) is still showing (0 rows) after I create tables.  Display tables (\dt) returns "Did not find any relations".  Any ideas why?  THANK YOU

Comment: They are not on the `search_path`. But that is unrelated.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Again, Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You only granted USAGE on the schema, not CREATE.